The ultimate backgammon
The following position, where one player has borne off all their checkers while all of the other player's checkers are on the bar (thus losing a backgammon), is reachable by a legal sequence of dice rolls and checker movements from the standard starting position of backgammon.

How can this position be reached in the fewest number of turns? To clarify

A player rolling both dice and then moving their checkers (or not) based on the numbers rolled constitutes a turn. A player rolls even if they have checkers on the bar but their opponent's home board is completely closed (two or more checkers on each of the home board's six points).
At the start of the game each player rolls one die, then the higher roller makes their first move based on the numbers shown on both dice. This counts as one turn.


Some observations: the shortest game is 17 turns by your metric, since 34 dice movements must be made, which can be done in 9 own turns (since 8x4+2(1st move)=34)(so 9x2-1=17 turns by your metric) (example game). However, this is clearly insufficient to hit all opponent's checkers (just consider the opponents' checkers starting on our point 19). I suspect an optimal solution consists of intentionally being hit once, and using the hit checker to hit the opponent. I expect the solution to need at least 3 more own turns, making 23 turns by your metric.

I can get a backgammon in

 25 ply: 
 6-3 24/21 13/7
 3-3 24/21 13/10 8/5 6/3
 6-6 4×13/7
 1-1 13/12 13/11 8/7
 5-5 3×8/3 7/2
 4-4 13/9 6/2 24/16
 5-5 4×7/2
 5-2 6/4* 6/1*
 2-1 bar/24* bar/23*
 2-2
 2-2 24/22*/20* 23/21*/19*
 2-2
 2-2 20/18*/16* 19/17*/15*
 2-2
 2-2 16/14*/12* 15/13*/11
 2-2
 3-3 12/9*/6 11/5
 2-2
 2-2 6/4* 3×2/off
 2-2
 6-6 4×6/off
 2-2
 6-6 6/off 5/off 4/off 3/off
 2-2
 3-3 2×3/off 2×2/off 


 The setup feels suboptimal, so 23 may be possible.


You're wrong at 5-4 13/9 6/1. 6/1 will hit a checker and the next move has to get it back onto the board.

That error was probably copied over by accident from an earlier version of this answer - it should be fixed now.
